# How to show a link to related records in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Let's say I have an Accounts table with an one-to-many relationship with Orders. When viewing a list of Accounts in ActiveAdmin, I'd like to display a link to the related Orders for that Account.

How might I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question. Links depend on your routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your admin/order.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do

    ..
  belongs_to :account

  ..
end
```

This will give you a route that looks something like this:

```
admin_account_orders GET  /admin/accounts/:account_id/orders(.:format) admin/orders#index
```

Which you can use, e.g., like this in your admin/account.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Account do
  ....

  index do
     ....
    column "Orders" do |a|
      link_to a.orders.count, admin_account_orders_path(a)
    end 
    ....
  end
  .....
end
```